# Issue with Thumbnail Display in Google Search Results

Tags: google-search-console, html, robots.txt, meta-keywords

I have a small startup, and I created a basic website in HTML for my company. Everything is fine, except whenever I google search my company name, it shows this random thumbnail on the right side of the search results.

I tried restricting crawling using robots.txt, but the issue persists. I want no thumbnail to appear on the right side of searches in any search engine. Thank you in advance.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow">
<meta name="robots" content="nositelinkssearchbox">
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive">
<meta name="robots" content="nosnippet">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noimageindex">
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to find an official way to do it, but so far I've been unable to. You can try to add the thumbnail meta tag, and point to a blank image: <meta name="thumbnail" content="http://example/foo.jpg" />